# Set selected option by default on angular template

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

The option which is setted like default is not selected on the browser

```
<select  name="category" id= "category" [(ngModel)] = "movie.category" #category="ngModel">
           <option value="default" disabled="true" selected>Choose one option</option>
           <option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [value]="cat">{{cat}}</option>
</select>
```

Appears disabled but not selected

Comment: Try setting movie.category to "default" in your component.ts. The ngModel seems to have an higher priority than the selected attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Selected attribute by will overwritten by ngModel value (model=>view changes). Remove selected attr from html and make ngModel initial value to 'default'

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your `component`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.movie.category = 'default';
}
```

You can also remove the `selected` *attribute* on your *default* option, and `disabled="true"` is unnecessary, it can be just `disabled`:

```
<option value="default" disabled>Choose one option</option>
```